# Table does not show all columns in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, rows

If I run the program then the only column that will be filled in the table will be the "description" column. Still, if I click on the row then it shows me all the details that should be shown in the table.

Here is the source code that I have written:
http://pastebin.com/Se3DnxJT

I have tried working along examples I have found but I don't see the issue in my code.

Can anyone help me by telling me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cellValueFactory` is not properly configured. The constructor of `PropertyValueFactory` accepts the name of the field and not the text to be displayed on the TableColumn. So the declaration of the columns should be as follows :

```
TableColumn designIdCol = new TableColumn("Design ID");
designIdCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Design, String>("id"));

TableColumn designNameCol = new TableColumn("Design Name");
designNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Design, String>("name"));

TableColumn printsAvailableCol = new TableColumn("Prints Available");
printsAvailableCol.setCellValueFactory(
                         new PropertyValueFactory<Design, String>("availability"));

TableColumn partDescriptionCol = new TableColumn("Description");
partDescriptionCol.setCellValueFactory(
                          new PropertyValueFactory<Design, String>("description"));
```